# Couldn't get the output "Username has been used!" when I have entered the username that has been stored in the database

Tags: java, android, firebase

[This's the database structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eEepj.png)

**Database Reference**

```
DatabaseReference referSales;
referSales = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Sales");
```

**Username Validation (Including Password Validation )**

```
referSales.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                if(!(edtPassword.getText().toString()).equals(edtConfirmPassword.getText().toString())) {
                    loadingDialog.dismiss();
                    Toast.makeText(Registration.this, "Password and Confirm Password are not identical!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    if(dataSnapshot.child(edtUsername.getText().toString()).exists()){
                    loadingDialog.dismiss();
                    Toast.makeText(Registration.this, "Username has been used!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
```

**Update Database**

When the username entered is not duplicated with the username stored in the database, the password and confirm password are identical, the new user information will be added to the database.

```
                }else{
                    loadingDialog.dismiss();
                    final Sales salesperson = new Sales(edtFirstName.getText().toString(),edtLastName.getText().toString(),
                            edtPhoneNo.getText().toString(),edtEmail.getText().toString(), edtUsername.getText().toString(),
                            edtPassword.getText().toString(),edtConfirmPassword.getText().toString());
                    referSales.child(edtUsername.getText().toString()).setValue(salesperson).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> salesperson) {
                            if(salesperson.isSuccessful()){
                                Toast.makeText(Registration.this, "Added Successfully!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                finish();
                            }
                        }
                    });

                }

            }
```

Comment: try using trim()

Answer (score 0):

You can query the database for the to check if the username has already been used in your database.

```
 Query query = databaseReference.child("users").orderByChild("userName")
                    .equalTo(edtUserName.getText().toString().trim();

query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                    if(dataSnapshot.exists()){
                        //user exist

                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Usename Has been used" ,
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }else{

                        //CREATE THE USER
                    }

                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });
```

Comment: This portion of code is the same as what I have done. I have tried to replace mine with your code, but the result is still remain the same.